# Ruby Regex Code String

Tags: ruby, regex, string

I have the following logic

```
def insert_type(type_list, user_input)
  case user_input
  when user_input == 'library_1'
    type_list.slice!('library_' + RegEx for any digit after library_ and stop right there + '__')
    type_list << user_input << '__'
  when user_input == 'class_A_2'
    type_list.slice!('class_' + RegEx for any digit after class_ and stop right there + _A + '__')
    type_list << user_input << '__'
  end
end
```

I tried to do the following

```
[l][i][b][r][a][r][y][_]\d{0,5} #digit from 0 to 99999
```

It does work, but there should be a more conventional way out there where I could start with l, and ends with the underscore, then add the number since type_list could be:

```
puts type_list
=> "username_John__userid_58173__userpass_8adsh20__class_A_2__library_0__"
```

Comment: I don't really get what you want to do. Can't you just split along `__` (double underscore)?

Comment: Looks like this is what you are looking for `\w+\d{0,5}`

Comment: \w+\d{0,5} takes all the string though

Comment: @nhahtdh true, if I know how to take from 'l' to 'y' from 'library' I could do it up to __. :D but how do you that?

Comment: Not sure what you want to do, but if you split type_list with http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-split along __, you get [username_John, userid_58173, userpass_8adsh20, class_A_2, library_0]. Then for each member, you can split it again.

Comment: @nhahtdh Oh, no I'm testing RegEx, not the String. And it's been solved. Thanks for participating. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is this:

```
\w+?(\d{1,5})
```

Or if you want a specific word, then:

```
library_(\d{1,5})
```

It will non-greedily capture the word characters, then add the numerical value to the first capture group.

- Basic example: http://regex101.com/r/xE0sM0
- Using your output: http://regex101.com/r/aV6yX6 (not sure if you want to match this?)

Explained:

- Any word character, including _, non greedy until we find a number
- Any number, from 1 to 5 digits (using {0,5} here would actually be 0 to 5 digits)
- Wrapping the digit in parentheses `()` allows the value to be captured.

Comment: thank you, but what if the word that I wanted is library? Since type_list has other words inside the string and library isn't always be the first word?

Comment: If you specifically want library, then just use `library_(\d{1,5})`

Comment: :O Didn't know you could do that! Thank you, sir!